# Problema con AlertDialog

Tags: alertdialog, stack

Estoy utilizando un AlertDialog en una aplicación que tiene una alarma de tiempo, disparada por un receptor de broadcast, con un Intent que lo manda primero al MainActivity, y de ahí a una SegundaActivity, desde donde se dispara el AlertDialog.

```
public class ReceptorBroadcats extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static boolean activar_alarma = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //coloca flag de alarma en curso para avisar a Main2Activity_Lactancia
        activar_alarma = true;

        //puesta en pantalla de la app para avisar de una nueva comida
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Cuando la aplicación está en el stack funciona perfectamente.

Cuando elimino la aplicación del stack funciona bien la primera vez, pero las veces subsiguientes abre directamente la pantalla de la SegundaActivity sin pasar por MainActivity ni por OnCreate de la SegundaActivity, de modo que no se activa el AlertDialog.

Se agradece mucho la ayuda.

Saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te sugerimos agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask] que te brinda información de como realizar preguntas en el sitio y estas sean bien recibidas, saludos.

Comment: Es como si el intent no se ejecutara.

Comment: Te sugiero agregar MainActivity , debe tener un código que hace se abra SegundaActivity, te recomiendo comentar como están configuradas tus Activity dentro del AndroidManiest.xml